# MPI - error loading shared libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, mpi, linker-errors

The problem I faced has been solved here:
[Loading shared library in open-mpi/ mpi-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368215/loading-shared-library-in-open-mpi-mpi-run)

I know not how, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or specifying `-x LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fixes the problem, when my installation itself specifies the necessary -L arguments. My installation is in `~/mpi/`

I have also included my compile-link configs.

```
$ mpic++ -showme:version 
mpic++: Open MPI 1.6.3 (Language: C++)

$ mpic++ -showme
g++ -I/home/vigneshwaren/mpi/include -pthread -L/home/vigneshwaren/mpi/lib
-lmpi_cxx -lmpi -ldl -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic -lrt -lnsl -lutil -lm -ldl

$ mpic++ -showme:libdirs
/home/vigneshwaren/mpi/lib

$ mpic++ -showme:libs
mpi_cxx mpi dl m rt nsl util m dl    % Notice mpi_cxx here %
```

When I compiled with `mpic++ <file>` and ran with `mpirun a.out` I got a (shared library) linker error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_cxx.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error has been fixed by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The question is how and why? What am i missing? Why is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` required when my installation looks just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`libdl`, `libm`, `librt`, `libnsl` and `libutil` are all essential system-wide libraries and they come as part of the very basic OS installation. `libmpi` and `libmpi_cxx` are part of the Open MPI installation and in your case are located in a non-standard location that must be explicitly included in the linker search path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

It is possible to modify the configuration of the Open MPI compiler wrappers and make them pass the `-rpath` option to the linker. `-rpath` takes a library path and appends its to a list, stored inside the executable file, which tells the runtime link editor (a.k.a. the dynamic linker) where to search for libraries before it consults the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. For example, in your case the following option would suffice:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/home/vigneshwaren/mpi/lib
```

This would embed the path to the Open MPI libraries inside the executable and it would not matter if that path is part of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at run time or not.

To make the corresponding wrapper add that option to the list of compiler flags, you would have to modify the `mpiXX-wrapper-data.txt` file (where `XX` is `cc`, `c++`, `CC`, `f90`, etc.), located in `mpi/share/openmpi/`. For example, to make `mpicc` pass the option, you would have to modify `/home/vigneshwaren/mpi/share/openmpi/mpicc-wrapper-data.txt` and add the following to the line that starts with `linker_flags=`:

```
linker_flags= ... -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib
```

`${prefix}` is automatically expanded by the wrapper to the current Open MPI installation path.

Comment: Be sure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't being overwitten in your `.bashrc` like mine was with CUDA. You want something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I just simply appends

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/PATH_TO_openmpi-version/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For example

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openmpi-1.8.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

into `$HOME/.bashrc` file and then source it to active again `source $HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: to find it (e.g. on a large cluster) use `whereis openmpi`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I installed **mpich 3.2** using the following command on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install mpich
```

When I tried to run the mpi process using **mpiexec**, I got the same error.

```
/home/node1/examples/.libs/lt-cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Configuring **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** didn't fix my problem.

I did a search for the file **'libmpi.so.0'** on my machine but couldn't find it. Took me some time to figure out that **'libmpi.so.0'** file is named as **'libmpi.so'** on my machine. So I renamed it to **'libmpi.so.0'**.

*It solved my problem!*

If you are having the same problem and you installed the library through apt-get, then do the following.

The file **'libmpi.so'** should be in the location **'/usr/lib/**'. Rename the file to **'libmpi.so.0'**

`mv /usr/lib/libmpi.so /usr/lib/libmpi.so.0`

After that **MPI** jobs should run without any problem.

If **'libmpi.so'** is not found in **'/usr/lib'**, you can get its location using the following command.

```
whereis libmpi.so
```

Answer (score 0):

first, run this command

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcr-dev
```

if still have this problem then configure LD_LIBRARY_PATH like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mpich-3.2.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then add it to ~/.bashrc before this line:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply running

```
$ ldconfig
```

appears to me as a better way to solve the problem (taken from a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) question). In particular, since it avoids misuse of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and [here](https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180), for why I believe it's misused to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: That is valid for system wide install and requires config **and** root access. This does not work for non root users and/or when multiple versions are installed.