# Error in loading shared libraries

Tags: centos, mpi

Hello all i am a student of bioinformatics and working on gromacs , while preparing for a simulation , i am getting this error

[root@compute-0-3 bin]# pdb2gmx -f model-317.pdb -water spce

**pdb2gmx: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory****

How to solve this problem ??

Comment: You have to first find out what MPI implementation was used to build the GROMACS executable. It could be Open MPI, MPICH, MVAPICH, Intel MPI, etc. Then you have to make sure that the library is installed on the node. (Who the heck gave you root access to a compute node?!)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH you can check more on [MPI - error loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769599/mpi-error-loading-shared-libraries)

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

I have found it useful to use `strace -eopen COMMAND` to see which files are actually searched for, and what return code open gives for each of them. For instance:

```
$ strace -eopen echo foo
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
foo
```

Use this trick to verify if it is just the path that is set wrong.

Also `libmpi.so.0` may not be properly installed. You might have the file `libmpi.so.0.1.2.3`, and you need to either run ldconfig or manually make a symlink from `libmpi.so.0` to `libmpi.so.0.1.2.3`. See more about why shared libraries might have different numbers appended to them here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: `ldd -r COMMAND` does nearly the same, except it doesn't show `dlopen()`-ed libraries.

Comment: True. However, `ldd` is not very helpful when the library is missing, as it doesn't tell you which paths has been tried.