# OpenMpi 1.6.5 Undefined symbol : ompi_mpi_real

Tags: openmpi

I'm stuck with an error in which I don't know what else to do :(

Please help!

> symbol lookup error:
>   /ompi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1: undefined symbol:
>   ompi_mpi_real

Thanks in advance!

ps: I've already googled a lot and found nothing related to this error :/ So.. if you could help.

Best Regards.

Comment: It will greatly help if you could provide the command that causes the error. You are probably using the wrong link command since `ompi_mpi_real` is defined in `libmpi.so.1` and that should be linked in automatically if you use `mpic++` as linker.

Comment: Hello @Hristo! I did something simple like mpicxx conftest.cpp | mpic++ conftest.cpp. It generates de executable but prints this error.

Comment: Got it! My LD_LIBRARY_PATH was actually linked to another MPI implementation. I got another error reporting that it couldn't load shared libraries and this solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769599/mpi-error-loading-shared-libraries
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

How about upgrading to Open MPI 1.8?  It was recently released and is the next generation stable series for Open MPI.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Imma give it a try. Now that I've fixed it. I need to optimize it and that's a good start :)